# I am not getting Any value in dataMapQuarter Map

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

```
     drawingOilTrialMonitoring = [Select Id,Action_Taken_Date__c,Additive_Addition__c,After_Top_Up_Concentration__c,After_Top_Up_Date__c,After_Trial_Image__c,Before_Top_Up_Conecntration__c,Before_Top_Up_Date__c,Before_Trial_Image__c,Charge_Date__c,Cleaner_Added_Ltr1__c,Cleaner_Filtration__c,Cleaner_Monitoring_Date__c,Cleaner_Monitoring_Month__c,Component__c,
                                         Contact_Number__c,Coolant__c,Customer_Name__c,Customer_Representative_Name__c,Customer_Singnature__c,Date_of_Trial__c,Department__c,End_Date__c,Job_Quantity__c,Machine_Number__c,Material__c,Name,Oil_Added_Ltr1__c,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.Account.Name ,PH_Date__c,PH_Value__c,Product_Name__c,Recomented_TDS_Value__c,Recommended_Concentration_Max__c,Recommended_Concentration_Min__c,Recommended_pH_value__c,
                                         Recommended_pH_value_Max__c,RecordTypeId,Remark__c,Select_Quarter__c,Select_Week__c,Start_Date__c,Tank_Cleaning__c,Tank_Cleaning_Date__c,Tank_Size__c,TDS__c,Tramp_Oil_Removal__c,Trial_Conduct_By__c,Water_Added_Ltr1__c ,RecordType.Name 
                                         FROM Trial_Initiation_And_Monitoring__c
                                         WHERE Id =: drawOilTrial];
            system.debug('drawingOilTrialMonitoring=>'+drawingOilTrialMonitoring);
            
            Map<String,TrialMonitorWrapper> dataMap =  new Map<String,TrialMonitorWrapper>() ;
            for(Trial_Initiation_And_Monitoring__c tm : drawingOilTrialMonitoring){
                TrialMonitorWrapper tmwrap = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                system.debug('tm=>'+tm);
                if(tm.Select_Week__c == '1st  Week'){
 System.debug('dataMap>> '+dataMap); 
                    if(dataMap != NULL && dataMap.containskey(tm.Product_Name__c) ){
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = dataMap.get(tm.Product_Name__c);
                        twrap.firstWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.beforeTrialImgUrl = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.Before_Trial_Image__c);
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlFirstQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        // twrap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                    else{
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                        twrap.firstWeekRecord = tm;
                         twrap.beforeTrialImgUrl = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.Before_Trial_Image__c);
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlFirstQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        dataMap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
 System.debug('dataMap>> '+dataMap); 
                    }
                }
                if(tm.Select_Week__c == '2nd Week'){
                    if(!dataMap.isEmpty() && dataMap.containskey(tm.Product_Name__c)){
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = dataMap.get(tm.Product_Name__c);
                        twrap.secondWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlSecond = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        // twrap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                    else{
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                        twrap.secondWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlSecond = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        dataMap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                }
                if(tm.Select_Week__c == '3rd Week'){
                    if(!dataMap.isEmpty() && dataMap.containskey(tm.Product_Name__c)){
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = dataMap.get(tm.Product_Name__c);
                        twrap.thirdWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlThird = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        // twrap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                    else{
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                        twrap.thirdWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlThird = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        dataMap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                }
                if(tm.Select_Week__c == '4th Week'){
                    if(!dataMap.isEmpty() && dataMap.containskey(tm.Product_Name__c)){
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = dataMap.get(tm.Product_Name__c);
                        twrap.fourthWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlFourth = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        // twrap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                    else{
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                        twrap.fourthWeekRecord = tm;
                        twrap.AfterTrialImgUrlFourth = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        dataMap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                }
                System.debug('dataMap>> '+dataMap); 
            } 
            //add data to list wrapper
            For(String key : dataMap.keySet()){
                TrialDataWrapper tdwp = new TrialDataWrapper();
                tdwp.productName = key;
                tdwp.trialData = dataMap.get(key);
                trialDataList.add(tdwp);
            }
            System.debug('trialDataList>> '+trialDataList); 
            // tdwrapper.trialData  = dataMap;
            // Assuming "dataMap" is the map containing TrialMonitorWrapper objects
            String productName = 'test 1'; // this is the dynamic product name
            String imgUrl = '';
            if (dataMap.containsKey(productName)) {
                TrialMonitorWrapper tmWrapper = dataMap.get(productName);
                if (tmWrapper.firstWeekRecord != null && tmWrapper.firstWeekRecord.Before_Trial_Image__c != null) {
                    // parse the img URL from the Before_Trial_Image__c field value
                    String beforeTrialImgHtml = tmWrapper.firstWeekRecord.Before_Trial_Image__c;
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('<img\\s+src="(.*?)".*?>');
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(beforeTrialImgHtml);
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        imgUrl = matcher.group(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            imgUrlBeforeImage = imgUrl;
            
            System.debug('imgUrl>> '+imgUrl); 
            
            System.debug('drawingOilTrialMonitoring >>>>>>>>> '+drawingOilTrialMonitoring); 
        }
        If (rustPreventive != null){
            rustPreventiveMonitoring = [Select Id,Action_Taken_Date__c,Additive_Addition__c,After_Top_Up_Concentration__c,After_Top_Up_Date__c,After_Trial_Image__c,Before_Top_Up_Conecntration__c,Before_Top_Up_Date__c,Before_Trial_Image__c,Charge_Date__c,Cleaner_Added_Ltr1__c,Cleaner_Filtration__c,Cleaner_Monitoring_Date__c,Cleaner_Monitoring_Month__c,Component__c,
                                        Contact_Number__c,Coolant__c,Customer_Name__c,Customer_Representative_Name__c,Customer_Singnature__c,Date_of_Trial__c,Department__c,End_Date__c,Job_Quantity__c,Machine_Number__c,Material__c,Name,Oil_Added_Ltr1__c,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.Account.Name ,PH_Date__c,PH_Value__c,Product_Name__c,Recomented_TDS_Value__c,Recommended_Concentration_Max__c,Recommended_Concentration_Min__c,Recommended_pH_value__c,
                                        Recommended_pH_value_Max__c,RecordTypeId,Remark__c,Select_Quarter__c,Select_Week__c,Start_Date__c,Tank_Cleaning__c,Tank_Cleaning_Date__c,Tank_Size__c,TDS__c,Tramp_Oil_Removal__c,Trial_Conduct_By__c,Water_Added_Ltr1__c ,RecordType.Name 
                                        FROM Trial_Initiation_And_Monitoring__c
                                        WHERE Id =: rustPreventive];
            System.debug('rustPreventiveMonitoring >>>>>>>>> '+rustPreventiveMonitoring); 

Map<String, TrialMonitorWrapper> dataMapQuarter = new Map<String, TrialMonitorWrapper>();
for(Trial_Initiation_And_Monitoring__c  tm1 : rustPreventiveMonitoring) {
    System.debug('tm1 => ' + tm1);
    if (tm1.Select_Quarter__c == '1st Quarter') {
        if (dataMapQuarter.containsKey(tm1.Product_Name__c)) {
            TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = dataMapQuarter.get(tm1.Product_Name__c);
            twrap1.firstQuarterRecord = tm1;
             System.debug('twrap1 for existing product name >> '+ twrap1.firstQuarterRecord);
            twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlFirstQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
            System.debug('twrap1 for existing product name >> '+ twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlFirstQuarter);
            twrap1.beforeTrialImgUrlQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.Before_Trial_Image__c);
            System.debug('twrap1 for existing product name >> '+ twrap1);
        } else {
            TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
            twrap1.firstQuarterRecord = tm1;
            twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlFirstQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
            twrap1.beforeTrialImgUrlQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.Before_Trial_Image__c);
            dataMapQuarter.put(tm1.Product_Name__c, twrap1);
            System.debug('twrap1 for new product name >> '+twrap1); 
            }
        }
        if (tm1.Select_Quarter__c == '2nd Quarter') {
            if (!dataMapQuarter.isEmpty() && dataMapQuarter.containsKey(tm1.Product_Name__c)) {
                TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = dataMapQuarter.get(tm1.Product_Name__c);
                twrap1.secondQuarterRecord = tm1;
                twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlSecondQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
            } else {
                TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                twrap1.secondQuarterRecord = tm1;
                twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlSecondQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
                dataMapQuarter.put(tm1.Product_Name__c, twrap1);
System.debug('dataMap1>> '+dataMapQuarter); 
            }
        }
        if (tm1.Select_Quarter__c == '3rd Quarter') {
            if (!dataMapQuarter.isEmpty() && dataMapQuarter.containsKey(tm1.Product_Name__c)) {
                TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = dataMapQuarter.get(tm1.Product_Name__c);
                twrap1.thirdQuarterRecord = tm1;
                twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlThirdQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
            } else {
                TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                twrap1.thirdQuarterRecord = tm1;
                twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlThirdQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
                dataMapQuarter.put(tm1.Product_Name__c, twrap1);
            }
        }
        if(tm1.Select_Quarter__c == '4th Quarter'){
                    if(!dataMapQuarter.isEmpty() && dataMapQuarter.containskey(tm1.Product_Name__c)){
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = dataMapQuarter.get(tm1.Product_Name__c);
                        twrap1.fourthQuarterRecord = tm1;
                        twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlFourthQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        // twrap.put(tm.Product_Name__c,twrap);
                    }
                    else{
                        TrialMonitorWrapper twrap1 = new TrialMonitorWrapper();
                        twrap1.fourthQuarterRecord = tm1;
                        twrap1.AfterTrialImgUrlFourthQuarter = GeneratePDFController.getImgeUrl(tm1.After_Trial_Image__c);
                        dataMapQuarter.put(tm1.Product_Name__c,twrap1);
                    }
                }
                System.debug('tm1.Product_Name__c: ' + tm1.Product_Name__c);
 //System.debug('twrap1: ' + twrap1);
System.debug('dataMap1: ' + dataMapQuarter); 
            } 
            //add data to list wrapper
            For(String key : dataMapQuarter.keySet()){
                TrialDataWrapper tdwp1 = new TrialDataWrapper();
                tdwp1.productName = key;
                tdwp1.trialDataQuater = dataMapQuarter.get(key);
                trialDataListForQuarter.add(tdwp1);
            }
           // System.debug('trialDataQuater>> '+trialDataQuater);
```

Is there any reason? I am setting all the value in record like product name and all , for the first loop drawingOil its getting all the values

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. You've dumped way too much code here -- cut it down to the essential bits that illustrate your issue and remove the debug statements